# how i rotate two edges in oposite direction?

Tags: modeling

just like the images describes what i am saying, i know there is a another post with the same question but it doesnt answer this so well, is it posible or not to do this?

what it does [image]

how it should be 
[image]

Comment: "i know there is a another post with the same question" can we know which post was it?

Comment: Delete any one face, add a mirror modifier, it mirrors opposite to the original, and apply it after you are done adjusting, as simple as that!